# Adding a custom product listing CMS block in shopware 6

Tags: shopware

I try adding a custom CMS block for product listing in shopware 6.
I can create other blocks for example image,text,... for those i don't have any problem.
But about product listing i have problem.I do the steps correctly according to this [document](http://%20https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to/custom-cms-block?category=shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to)

But in admin panel i can't see My CMS **block product listing**i have  only default product listing .
Also for test i change value **hidden:true** in **sw-cms/blocks/commerce/product-listing-exam/index.js** with this value my block appears.But doesn't work.i can use of my block in shop page layout type but i need use this in listing page layout 
There is my source code : [link](https://github.com/pedramham/cms-block-ptoduct-listing-shopware-6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you created the image/text elements, did that work without problems? I created a cms block according to the documentation, but the block does not appear in the block list. There is a file in public/administration/js folder in the example plugin. Do you know what that does? Maybe the problem is because of that.

Comment: After that you must to  " run bin/build-administration.sh " ..You do that

Comment: Where should the command be run ? In the directory of plugin? 
Are there any other parameters required?
Do you have any documentation link for it?

Comment: When I execute the command bin/build-administration.sh or sudo bin/build-administration.sh I just get a "command not found" error

Comment: After fixing the error cause, I executed the command and the whole administration broke, I get a Shopware not found error in the administration page